# Google Drive files watch webhook

Tags: c#, file, watch, drive

We have Google Drive webhook notification system within our Windows 2012 server, developped in C#.

We use Google.Apis.Drive.v3.dll library v. 1.25.0.862.
Request to activate webhook function by files/watch service work fine.
This service activate notifications within folder not file. FolderId is the function parameter.

Webhook notification from Drive working as well, after putting file in the folder but within 5 minutes
from activation. After this time notifications from Drive not working and we not receive 'update' message.

Time expiration in the channel is 6 hours and we receive confirmation in 'sync' message
and 'update' as well. Ex.: expiration: Thu, 12 Dec 2019 16:35:48 GMT.

Thanks for response.

Comment: You need to see if the connection closed.  From cmd.exe >Netstat -a which will give the the status of UDP and TCP connections.  The connecton may be closing due to a Keep-Alive option and when no messages are received the connection is closing.  The solution is to enable the keep alive when the client connects.